# Which book should I refer to learn Calculus

Tags: book-recommendation

I am in 11th grade just near finals. Well After my exams I wish to learn calculus from exact start (I know basic differentiaton like $x^n$ and such)

Comment: Introductory: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/what-are-the-recommended-textbooks-for-introductory-calculus and Advanced: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721705/advanced-calculus-book-recommendations-what-calculus-books-should-i-use-to-lea?rq=1

Comment: I hardly recommend you to look in youtube the introductory Linear Algebra and Calculus series of the channel 3blue1brown... its a masterpieces that will ease what your are going to find on any book